# Read/write permission on a nested folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a nested directory structure like this:

```
foo
   foobar
      foofoobar
```

In case I want to give a user read/write access to directory foofoobar, do I have to assign read/write access on foo and foobar as well?

The answer seems obvious (i.e. no), since such a requirement would present an obvious and laughable security hole

I think the only requirement is that the user has e**X**ecute permission on foo and foobar, so they can cd into foofoobar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement is that the user has "execute" permission on all the parent directories. When you modify the contents of `/foo/foobar/foofoobar`, it does *not* cause any changes in any of its parents directories, so read/write is not necessary.

- `+x /foo`
- `+x /foo/foobar`
- `+rwx /foo/foobar/foofoobar`.