# Allow user to traverse path to given directory

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

Say, I want to give a user `colleague` read access to a directory `/rather/long/path/to/the/directory`, but not necessarily to its parent directories.

As explained for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory) and [there](https://superuser.com/questions/259930/read-write-permission-on-a-nested-folder/259933#259933), I first need to make sure that `colleague` can traverse the path. Using `setfacl` :

```
setfacl -m u:colleague:x /rather
setfacl -m u:colleague:x /rather/long
setfacl -m u:colleague:x /rather/long/path
setfacl -m u:colleague:x /rather/long/path/to
setfacl -m u:colleague:x /rather/long/path/to/the
setfacl -m u:colleague:xr /rather/long/path/to/the/directory
```

This is quite tedious for a deeply nested path. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

P.S. To make it a bit harder, being a normal user I might not have the right to change the permissions for the top-level directory in the path (e.g. `/home`). If possible, the solution should either ignore these directories (assuming that `colleague` can traverse them) or, even better, check whether `colleague` is allowed to traverse them and give an error message, if he is not.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I can't test it and prove at the moment (my linux box is somewhere far away).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The simple, stupid answer:

You can *shorten* your sequence of commands a little by combining the first *n*–1 of them:

```
setfacl -m u:colleague:x  /rather /rather/long /rather/long/path /rather/long/path/to /rather/long/path/to/the
setfacl -m u:colleague:xr /rather/long/path/to/the/directory
```

#### An “obvious” warning:

Even if you own the target (leaf) directory,
you need to have execute (traverse) access to every directory in the path. 
If there’s any directory that you don’t have access to and you don’t own,
you’re out of luck. 
(You need to assume an identity (i.e., `root` or the owner of the directory)
that lets you give yourself access, or persuade somebody who has the power to do so. 
That’s out of the scope of this question.)

But, if there are intermediate directories that you own but don’t have access to
(e.g., somebody has done `chmod 0`), you need to give yourself access *from the top down*.

#### The answer: (TL;DR)

I made the above point because this works from the bottom up:

```
leaf="/rather/long/path/to/the/directory"
branch="$leaf"
while branch="$(dirname "$branch")"
do
     setfacl -m u:colleague:x "$branch"  ||  break
     if [ "$branch" = / ]
     then
         break
     fi
done
setfacl -m u:colleague:xr "$leaf"
```

Optionally, you can hide any error messages from `setfacl` by adding `2> /dev/null`. 
If you have a pathological situation where you own `/rather/long`
and `/rather/long/path/to`, but not `/rather/long/path` (but its permissions are open), remove the `||  break` after the `setfacl`, because you need to keep climbing the tree
after getting the error on `setfacl … /rather/long/path`. 
Otherwise, if you are not `root`, you *could* remove the `if [ "$branch" = / ]` test, because the loop will terminate when you reach a directory level
where you can’t run `setfacl`. 
(But that’s not a great idea; if you save this as a script,
you will someday run it as `root`, and then you’ll have an infinite loop.)

It goes without saying that, if you make this a script, the directory path and the colleague’s name should be parameters.